# Having a \dsum like we can have a \dfrac

Tags: math-operators, displaystyle

I'm a lazzy man and I would like to have a `\dsum` operator to avoid the use of `\displaystyle`. I have made a macro but it would be nice to have the possibility to write `\dsum_{k=1}^{n}` instead of `\dsum{k=1}{n}`.

Does a LaTeX sorcerer can help me ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\dsum[2]{{\displaystyle\sum_{#1}^{#2}}}

\begin{document}

$\dsum{k=1}{n} 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1$

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you use `\displaystyle` in text mode math instead of using a display math enviornment? That almost always leads to poor output. (this would be trivial to define using xparse `e` argument type which is designed for `^_` syntax but I would almost never use such a construct)

Comment: or better `\newcommand\dsum{\sum\limits}`

Comment: I have used `\displaystyle` because of my lake of knowledge about LaTeX; ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That does the job !

Comment: it would be much better ti use a standard `\sum`

Comment: You're totally right but sometime in high school I have to do ugly formattings just for my students.

Comment: why? students will find it easier to read well typeset math than badly set math, that is surely the point of typesetting? Why can you not set the math in display style, why a display style summation smashed into a text style formula so it looks so out of place?

Comment: I always like to have the possibility two way of formatting formulas. This allows to show the two ways to type things : the good one and the bad one.

Comment: OK you are forgiven:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

In almost all cases the third setting is preferable to the first two

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\dsumx{e{_^}}{{\displaystyle\sum_{#1}^{#2}}}

\newcommand\dsuml{\sum\limits}

\begin{document}

xparse\\
$\dsumx_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1$

limits\\
$\dsuml_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1$

standard
\[\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1\]
\end{document}
```

The first uses the display summation which is inappropriate for inline math.

The second uses the correct summation but the limits setting will still make the expression too tall to fit in an inline setting.

The third sets the expression as a display with appropriate summation layouts just using the standard `\sum`.

Comment: `\mathop{\displaystyle\sum}` would be better, imho, for `\dsumx`; no need for fancy `e` arguments.

Comment: @egreg I was assuming (hoping) that the large summation was actually  an unwanted side effect to get the limits layout.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xparse`'s `e` type parameter to parse it

[image]

This allows you to parse both `\dsum_{k=1}^{n}` and `\dsum^{n}_{k=1}`.

### Notes:

- The extra brace group to ensure that `\displaystyle` stays local.
- The `e{^_}` provides two arguments, `#`1 is the one given to `^` and `#2` is the one given to `_` (independent of the order they are provided in).  If no parameters of either type are given `\IfValueT{}` will not execute its parameter.  `\IfValueT{}` is a more efficient form of `\IfValueTF{}{}` and is useful when you only really need to do something under one condition.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dsum}{%
    e{^_}
}{%
  {% 
    \displaystyle\sum
    \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}
  }
}%

\begin{document}

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = \dsum_{k=1}^{n} 2^k = \dsum^{n}_{k=1} 2^k = 2^{n+1} - 1$ .

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the two `\IfValueT` work ?

Comment: @projetmbc xparse distinguishes between `\dsum_{}`  and `\dsum` in the latter case where `_` is not used at all the macro is passed a specal `--novalue--` token and the `IfValueT` test is provided to test for this case so here Peter is saying if you provide `_{foo}` to `\dsum` use `_{foo}` with the `\sum` in the macro. If `_` is not used by the user no `_` is used in the internal call to `\sum` (and then same test with `^`)

Comment: @projetmbc: Added explanation.

Comment: Very clear explanations. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I provide `\dsum` and `\Dsum`, depending on how you want the look of the `\textstyle` limits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xdsum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{88}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xtsum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{80}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\dsum}{\mathchoice{\Xdsum}{\Xdsum}{\Xtsum}{\Xtsum}}
\newcommand\Dsum{\dsum\limits}
\begin{document}
\centering
Sum and defined dsum and Dsum:\par
$\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i\quad \dsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \quad \Dsum_{i=1}^2 x_i $
\[\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i\quad \dsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \quad \Dsum_{i=1}^2 x_i\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

GuM asks that I comment on why I use the star version of `\DeclareMathOperator`.  It is to designate that, in `\displaystyle`, that limits are placed above and below the operator, rather than placed as super/sub-scripts.  If you remove the `*` you will see all limits in `\dsum` and `\Dsum` revert to super/sub-script limits.

Comment: The `\dsum` and `\displaystyle` versions are really too big for in text.  Even `\sum\limits` fouls up the baselines, but not as much.  @DavidCarlisle is right about this.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I wholly agree with you, but was just trying to give the OP what was asked for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I always agree with your last sentence.

Comment: I think you should spend a few words to explain why you need the starred version of `\DeclareMathOperator` (I’m assuming the reason is… well, see line 27 of `amsopn.sty`).

Comment: Oh, I’m sorry, I’ve noticed right now that in the displayed formula you use `\dsum`, not `\Dsum`: my reference to line 27 of `amsopn.sty` was meant to explain why, without the `*` after `\DeclareMathOperator`, even `\Dsum` is printed “without limits”.  In other words, I was erroneously assuming that you were omitting a much deeper explanation!  Thanks for heeding my advice, anyway. :-)

Comment: @GuM Your confusion convinced me to edit, adding all three cases to both text and display styles.  Thanks.